# SQLite Of AIR based on FlashBuilder Issues

Tags: sql, sqlite

I got this line after I debug my code:

> SQLError: 'Error #3115: SQL Error.', details:'near ',': syntax error', operation:'execute', detailID:'2003'.

I just want to delete some data from my database. Here is the function which made the error

```
private function deletes():void{
    stamt.text = "delete from AppUser where userName=@userName,password=@password,age=@age";
    stamt.parameters["@userName"] = "User_49";
    stamt.parameters["@password"] = "1234569";
    stamt.parameters["@age"] = 20;
    stamt.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use commas to separate conditions in a WHERE clause, you use logical operators such as AND and OR to form a single logical condition. You probably want this SQL:

```
delete from AppUser
where userName = @userName
  and password = @password
  and age = @age
```

so your code should be:

```
stamt.text = "delete from AppUser where userName=@userName and password=@password and age=@age";
```

You're probably thinking of UPDATE where you do use commas in the SET; for example:

```
update some_table
set a = 6, b = 11
where ...
```

but there you're building a list of updates rather than a single logical expression.